# Persisting data with JPA with existing datas

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, modelmapper

I want to persist an object like this one :

```
{
    "paymentMode": "CREDIT CARD",
    "totalAmount": 158.0,
    "orderProducts": [
        {
            "productKeyId": "HycaR7sPeecIMZEewanuK0jzPo7S33",
            "name": "Cornish crab salad, brown crab mayonnaise, toasted muffin",
            "price": 20.0,
            "qty": 1,
            "imgPath": "pathImage",
            "category": {
                "categoryKeyId": "23ume70Fu6yqyGUWfQkW110P4ko3gZ",
                "name": "Starter"
            }
        },...
    ],
    "seller": {
        "userKeyId": "qmNR5g2TD8Ja5KvA1DCQWzYj55nvbP",
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Vera",
        "email": "david.vera@9online.fr",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "addressKeyId": "2t7x0bFgP5B9Qb2ymnLL5aPZVwMFhJ",
                "city": "Vancouver",
                "country": "Canada",
                "streetName": "123 street name",
                "postalCode": "ABCCBA",
                "type": "billing",
            },...
        ]
     },
    "createdAt": "2019-10-22T09:48:06.000+0000"
}
```

Some object are already stored in Database such as seller, addresses, products and product category.

I created : Orders tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
@Getter @Setter
public class OrderEntity implements Serializable {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String orderKeyId;

    // A sale belong to one seller
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserEntity seller;

    private String paymentMode;

    private double totalAmount;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.order")
    @Valid
    private List<OrderProductEntity> orderProducts;
}
```

An order_product table (pivot table):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order_product")
@Getter @Setter
public class OrderProductEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonIgnore
    private OrderProductPK pk;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer qty;

    // default constructor
    public OrderProductEntity() {
        super();
    }
    public OrderProductEntity(OrderEntity order, ProductEntity product, Integer quantity) {
        pk = new OrderProductPK();
        pk.setOrder(order);
        pk.setProduct(product);
        this.qty = quantity;
    }

    @Transient
    public ProductEntity getProduct() {
        return this.pk.getProduct();
    }
    ...
}
```

And a product table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
@Getter @Setter
public class ProductEntity implements Serializable {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String productKeyId;

    // many to one relationship with category
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private CategoryEntity category;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double price;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int qty;

    private String imgPath;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Valid
    private List<OrderProductEntity> orderProducts;
}
```

The userEntity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter @Setter
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userKeyId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 120, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String encryptedPassword;

    private String emailVerificationToken;

    // column definition do not work for all database engine. So set the value to false is the same
    // @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean emailVerificationStatus = false;

    // One user can have Many Addresses
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<AddressEntity> addresses;
}
```

And finally the embedded class :

```
@Embeddable
@Getter @Setter
@ToString
public class OrderProductPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 476151177562655457L;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private OrderEntity order;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private ProductEntity product;

    ...
}
```

I created a controller method to persist orders in a MySQL database:

```
public OrderRest createOrder(@RequestBody OrderRequestModel orderRequestModel) throws Exception {

    OrderRest returnValue = new OrderRest();
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    OrderDto orderDto = modelMapper.map(orderRequestModel, OrderDto.class);

    OrderDto createdOrder = orderService.createOrder(orderDto);

    returnValue = modelMapper.map(createdOrder, OrderRest.class);

    // 5. Return the expected object
    return returnValue;
}
```

I have an orderDTO object that contains several fields (including ID).

```
public class OrderDto implements Serializable {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String orderKeyId;
    private String paymentMode;
    private double totalAmount;
    private List<ProductDto> orderProducts;
    private UserDto seller;
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

My productDTO object

```
public class ProductDto implements Serializable {
    // ommit this member and do not generate getter / setter
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String productKeyId;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int qty;
    private String imgPath;

    private CategoryDto category = new CategoryDto();
}
```

The UserDto :

```
@Getter @Setter
@ToString
public class UserDto implements Serializable {
    // ommit this member and do not generate getter / setter
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private String userKeyId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String encryptedPassword;
    private String emailVerificationToken;
    private Boolean emailVerificationStatus = false;

    private List<AddressDto> addresses;
//    private List<RoleDto> roles;
}
```

the controller is calling my service layer :

```
@Override
public OrderDto createOrder(OrderDto orderDto) {
    // create a new order
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    OrderEntity orderEntity = modelMapper.map(orderDto, OrderEntity.class);

    String orderKeyId = utils.generateOrderKeyId(30);
    orderEntity.setOrderKeyId(orderKeyId);
    orderEntity.setCreatedAt(orderDto.getCreatedAt());
    orderEntity.setPaymentMode(orderDto.getPaymentMode());
    orderEntity.setTotalAmount(orderDto.getTotalAmount());

    // set the seller
    UserEntity userEntity = modelMapper.map(orderDto.getSeller(), UserEntity.class);
    orderEntity.setSeller(userEntity);

    List<OrderProductEntity> orderProductEntities = new ArrayList<>();
    // set the products
    for (int i = 0; i < orderDto.getOrderProducts().size(); i++) {
        ProductDto productDto = orderDto.getOrderProducts().get(i);
        OrderProductEntity orderProductEntity = modelMapper.map(orderDto.getOrderProducts().get(i), OrderProductEntity.class);
        orderProductEntities.add(orderProductEntity);
        orderDto.getOrderProducts().set(i, productDto);
    }
    orderEntity.setOrderProducts(orderProductEntities);


    OrderEntity storedOrder = orderRepository.save(orderEntity);
    OrderDto returnValue = modelMapper.map(storedOrder, OrderDto.class);

    return returnValue;
}
```

I have 3 issues : 
I save the order in the database but the seller is not persisted

[image]

In the order product table datas are not persisted. 
[image]

And i obtain an error message in my rest response :

```
"trace": "org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors: Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.CollectionConverter@685b36d6 failed to convert java.util.List to java.util.List.error...
```

Comment: Is it possible that you've not annotated the seller relation (OrderEntity-UserEntity) correctly? Maybe show the UserEntity and UserDto classes as well.

Comment: I updated my post...